# ¿Como configurar la carpeta Windows para cada usuario que va a contener varios .ini en un terminal server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server

He instalado una aplicación en en servidor con Windows Server 2012, esta genera varios .ini en el directorio C:\Windows. Si varios usuarios usan esta aplicación, cada uno con su sesión remota, siempre toma los .ini que están guardados en ese directorio, pero he visto el mismo programa en otros servidores con WS2012, donde cada usuario tiene su carpeta Windows en C:\Users_usuario_\Windows, donde solo guarda los archivos de configuración que genera el programa.

No es una configuración de este, de eso puedo estar seguro seguro (trabajo con los desarrolladores). He estado revisando las variables de entorno, active directory, configuraciones de usuarios, etc. pero no puedo dar con la solución.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Corrección primer párrafo: C:\Users\ _usuario_ \Windows

Comment: Hola! esta pregunta no es de programación, por lo que se sale del alcance de esta web. Tendrás más suerte preguntando en https://superuser.com